# Fullcalendar nowIndicator sits at midnight, unless calendar is started with resourceTimelineDay

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

When I try to initialize a calendar with anything other than resourceTimelineDay, the nowIndicator doesn't show up in the right place.  If I start it with resourceTimelineMonth, it sticks at midnight.  If I start it with resourceTimelineWeek, it sticks at the beginning of the hour.  If I start it with resourceTimelineDay though, it starts with the correct time, and holds, even if I change the view to week or month view.

I would like to start with month view, and have the nowIndicator show where it is supposed to.  This used to work with V3, but now, with V5, it isn't working.

Here is it started with resourceTimelineMonth:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    timeZone: 'America/Phoenix',
    nowIndicator: true,
    initialView: 'resourceTimelineMonth',
    aspectRatio: 1.5,
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineWeek,resourceTimelineMonth'
    },
    editable: true,
    resourceAreaHeaderContent: 'Rooms',
    resources: 'https://fullcalendar.io/api/demo-feeds/resources.json?with-nesting&with-colors',
    events: 'https://fullcalendar.io/api/demo-feeds/events.json?single-day&for-resource-timeline'
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#calendar {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.11.3/main.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.11.3/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Here it is started with resourceTimelineDay:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    timeZone: 'America/Phoenix',
    nowIndicator: true,
    initialView: 'resourceTimelineDay',
    aspectRatio: 1.5,
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineWeek,resourceTimelineMonth'
    },
    editable: true,
    resourceAreaHeaderContent: 'Rooms',
    resources: 'https://fullcalendar.io/api/demo-feeds/resources.json?with-nesting&with-colors',
    events: 'https://fullcalendar.io/api/demo-feeds/events.json?single-day&for-resource-timeline'
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#calendar {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.11.3/main.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.11.3/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Neither `resourceTimelineWeek`, nor `resourceTimelineMonth` work as expected, even if you switch to day view.

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not how it should be done, in my opinion, but it appears there is no official way to change the behavior of the nowIndicator.  In lieu of that, the hack is to start in `resourceTimelineDay` view and change the view to `resourceTimelineWeek` or `resourceTimelineMonth` view immediately after the calendar is rendered.

```
calendar.render();
calendar.changeView('resourceTimelineMonth');
```

This is a hack, and hopefully there will be a fix for this in some future release.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    timeZone: 'America/Phoenix',
    nowIndicator: true,
    initialView: 'resourceTimelineDay',
    aspectRatio: 1.5,
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineWeek,resourceTimelineMonth'
    },
    editable: true,
    resourceAreaHeaderContent: 'Rooms',
    resources: 'https://fullcalendar.io/api/demo-feeds/resources.json?with-nesting&with-colors',
    events: 'https://fullcalendar.io/api/demo-feeds/events.json?single-day&for-resource-timeline'
  });

  calendar.render();
  calendar.changeView('resourceTimelineMonth');
});
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#calendar {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.11.3/main.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.11.3/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id='calendar'></div>
```